# How to set up web app to talk to Parse Server (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I have Parse Server running on AWS and I wonder how to save an object to it. I'm not sure how to connect to Parse Server in my javascript file...

Do I do something like:

var Parse = require('parse');

Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID");

Parse.serverURL = 'http://mypath'

Also, how do I include the Parse SDK in my js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Parse.initialize("518e0dbca14e73748f81e550e12deea515ff959e");
    Parse.serverURL = 'http://ec2-35-165-199-91.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:80/parse';
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var gameScore = new GameScore();
    gameScore.save({playerName: "Kir"}).then(function(object) {
        alert("yay! it worked");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```